# Integrating TinyMCE to Angular2 - problem on ngOnDestroy

Tags: angular, tinymce, angular2-routing

In an Angular2 app, when we load a big picture (more than 2MB) into the tinyMCE editor as image:Base64 or blob, and when we navigate away from the page, it takes longer to finalize the navigation including the load of the new module. In chrome dev tools, all I can see is that rendering takes longer to finish and there is a Long Task.

Not only do I not know what is causing this, but in firefox, this works like a charm. Again, if there is no image in editor or a small one, navigation works in both browsers.

Now little background, this is a legacy code and I assume that they integrated tinyMCE into Angular2 following this tutorial https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/angular-2-and-tinymce/.

This is the init of tinymce:

```
tinymce.init({
        relative_urls: false,
        document_base_url: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/' + window.location.pathname.split('/')[1],
        skin_url: 'assets/skins/lightgray',
        menubar: false,
        statusbar: false,
        selector: '#' + this.elementId,
        branding: false,
        readonly: 1,
        plugins: ['link', 'table', 'image', 'autoresize'],
        toolbar: false,
        autoresize_min_height: 200,
        default_link_target: '_blank',
        extended_valid_elements: 'a[href|target=_blank]',
        setup: (editor: any) => {
            this.ed = editor;
        },
        images_dataimg_filter: function (img) {
            return img.hasAttribute('internal-blob');
        }
    });
```

After some experimenting and thinking, I removed the ngOnDestroy call and with it tinymce.remove() and it worked!
I really want to understand why though. Any suggestions and thoughts?

Comment: may be the this.ed property is not working because the this is the class of tinymce and not the class tinymce is in.

Comment: Could be, I'll check. But something like that would result in same behaviour in any browser.

Comment: Could be that without tinymce.remove() you are using the same Instance. May be the remove fails, for a part so you can't use that Instance anymore. tinymce is buggy by default :-)